# Is there a way to close the monitor but does not lock the computer for Windows 8.1, where this setting option is unavailable

Tags: windows, windows-8, display, hardware

I want to close the monitor, but leave everything else running in the background, just like the monitor is plugged off - but it's a laptop, so you won't find a power button, and no relevant fn key is found though some laptop has this feature.

Is there a software for that?

I've tried some, even found a WINAPI to close the screen, but all of them just lock the whole system.

I think this requires some system configuration, since in a majority versions of Windows there is a setting option for that, but not in this specific version of Windows 8.1.

Running a black splash is a workaround, but in this way the monitor is not really turned off.

Comment: I normally set the computer to never sleep nor hibernate but turn of the screen in the power options (I'm sure this was available in windows 8, but I can't recheck right now). The bad part was waiting 15minutes (or whatever value I set that wouldn't disrupt my daily use) before the screen actually went black. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Mefitico This is exactly what I have always done, and I can confirm it works great.  I typed it up as an answer because I think it's the best solution and you were not able to confirm at this time.

Comment: @Mefitico Thank you! I've tried this solution long ago, but unfortunately some of the Windows version has not this option, for example a specific version of Windows 8.1. The newest Windows 10 works totally fine.

Comment: If an indirect apporach is admissible, have you tried using some software that inhibits windows hibernation? In qBitorrent -> Tool -> Options -> Behavior, scroll down, check mark "Inhibit system sleep"

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a laptop computer, you will find there is a power button on the monitor that one can press to turn off the screen. It will not impact the operation of the computer.

Comment: haha O(∩_∩)O lol

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can accomplish this task without even needing any additional software:

1. Open the Windows `Power Options` control panel.
2. Create a new power profile.
3. Set the power profile to never sleep.
4. Set the power profile to turn off the display after x minutes.  For your needs, you may want to set this to 1 minute.

That's it!  Your monitor will now turn off after 1 minute of no keyboard or pointing device activity, and applications will continue to run.

Co-authoriship of this answer goes to Mefitico.

Comment: Thank you. But some of the Windows version has not this option, for example a specific version of Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Aoyama You're welcome. Are you comfortable editing the Windows registry?  If so, I can take a look and see if the control panel is just changing a couple of registry values.  I'll also take a look at a couple tools that I have in mind for you that might do the job.  If you need this right away, let me know, and I'll make it a priority (meaning 1-4 days, versus 1+ weeks).

Comment: That's very kind of you, I'm free with registry. It's not urgent, just for personal interest that wanna know how to make it work. It will be a great job, since there's no such kind of information online.